# FFmpeg - RTMP streaming from NodeJS, stream is faster than realtime

Tags: javascript, video, ffmpeg, video-streaming, html5-video

My goal is to render a canvas in Node, and stream that canvas to an RTMP server (Twitch ultimately, but for now I'm **testing on a local RTMP server**). The standard way to stream to RTMP seems to be `ffmpeg`, so I'm using that, spawned as a child process from within NodeJS.

I've tried a bunch of different combinations of techniques and `ffmpeg` params to get a consistent framerate and a stream at "realtime" speed, but can't figure it out. Here's the paths I've gone down so far

#### Render canvas and send input in continuous interval

```
import { createCanvas } from 'canvas';

const canvas = createCanvas(1920, 1080);
const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

const fps = 30;
const ffmpeg = spawn('ffmpeg', [
  '-re',
  '-framerate', String(.fps),
  '-r', String(fps),

  '-i', '-',
  
  '-vcodec', 'libx264',
  '-r', String(fps),
  '-s', '1920x1080',
  '-g:v', String(2*fps),
  '-c:a', 'aac',
  '-f', 'flv', 'rtmp://127.0.0.1/live'
]);
ffmpeg.stdout.pipe(process.stdout)
ffmpeg.stderr.pipe(process.stderr)


const send = () => {
  ctx.fillStyle = 'red'
  ctx.fillRect(0, 0, 1920, 1080);
  ctx.font = '100px Arial';
  ctx.fillStyle = 'black'
  ctx.fillText(new Date().toLocaleString(), 500, 500);
  ffmpeg.stdin.write(canvas.toBuffer())
  setImmediate(() => send())
}
send()
```

###### Observations

- Took about 35 seconds for the stream to actually start (I think because of ffmpeg needing some amount of time to analyze the input?)
- Frame rate extremely below what I set it to, and "speed" also very low, although I'm not 100% sure what this means. example log `Frame=  906 fps=3.9 q=29.0 size= 311kB time=00:00:27.83 bitrate= 91.5kbits/s speed=0.119x`
- **Stream behavior**

  - Takes about a minute to load once opened in VLC
  - Timer on the stream starts about 1 minute behind real time, stays stuck on a single second for 30+ seconds, then shoots up a few seconds quickly, and gets stuck again

I had a hunch here that at least some of the reason for the strange behavior was that rendering the canvas in the same loop that I send input to `ffmpeg` in was too slow to achieve 30 FPS.

#### Render canvas in separate interval from ffmpeg input interval

Only render canvas FPS-times per second

Continue sending input to `ffmpeg` as fast as possible

```
import { createCanvas } from 'canvas';

const canvas = createCanvas(1920, 1080);
const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

let buffer = canvas.toBuffer();

const fps = 30;
const ffmpeg = spawn('ffmpeg', [
  ...same as before
]);

const render = () => {
  ctx.fillStyle = 'red'
  ctx.fillRect(0, 0, 1920, 1080);
  ctx.font = '100px Arial';
  ctx.fillStyle = 'black'
  ctx.fillText(new Date().toLocaleString(), 500, 500);
  buffer = canvas.toBuffer();
  setTimeout(() => render(), 1/fps)
}
render();

const send = () => {
  ffmpeg.stdin.write(buffer)
  setImmediate(() => send())
}
send()
```

###### Observations

- `ffmpeg` starts streaming almost immediately
- fps starts out around 16, takes a couple seconds to hit 28, and then ~30 more seconds to hit 30fps. speed much closer to 1x, but not quite all the way. example log `frame=15421 fps= 30 q=29.0 size=    4502kB time=00:08:31.66 bitrate=  72.1kbits/s speed=0.994x`
- **Stream behavior**

  - Takes about 5 seconds to load once opened in VLC
  - Timer stays stuck on the same second for multiple minutes

My hunch here for the stream being stuck on 1 timestamp is that while ffmpeg is sending frames *out* at 30 frames per second, I'm sending it frames much quicker than that. So in the first 1st of a second of streaming

1. Canvas renders with timestamp T 30 times
2. `send` runs N times where N is likely way higher than 30, sending `ffmpeg` N frames with the current timestamp
3. ffmpeg now has N frames with timestamp T on them, but can only send them out 30 per second, so it takes more than 1 second for the timestamp on the screen to change

#### Only send ffmpeg a frame every 1/FPS second

Same as before, but instead of sending ffmpeg frames as quickly as possible, only send it FPS frames every second.

```
import { createCanvas } from 'canvas';

const canvas = createCanvas(1920, 1080);
const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

let buffer = canvas.toBuffer();

const fps = 30;
const ffmpeg = spawn('ffmpeg', [
  ...same as before
]);

const render = () => {
  ...same as before
}
render();

const send = () => {
  ffmpeg.stdin.write(buffer)
  setTimeout(() => send(), 1/fps)
}
send()
```

###### Observations

- `ffmpeg` takes a few seconds to start streaming
- fps starts out high, around 28, and over the next minute or so drops down to 16. Speed drops along with it. example log `frame= 1329 fps= 16 q=29.0 size=     463kB time=00:00:41.93 bitrate=  90.5kbits/s speed= 0.5x`
- **Stream behavior**

  - Takes about 10 seconds to load once opened in VLC
  - Timer increases about twice as fast as expected, then gets hung on one second for a bit, and then starts increasing again at same rate

---

I'll stop there, but tl;dr I've tried a whole bunch of different combinations of `-re, -framerate, -fps_mode, -r` ffmpeg args, and some other techniques in the code like continuing to use `setImmediate` to send frames, but use a date comparison to actually send a frame at an FPS rate. I'm sure there's probably some fundamental video streaming knowledge I'm missing, so I'm just looking for any sort of guidance on how I can get my canvas to stream at a "realtime" speed, or whatever I could be missing here.

Comment: Why are you using both `'-framerate', String(.fps)` and `'-r', String(fps)`? Try without `'-framerate', String(.fps)`. You may also remove `'-r', String(fps),` after the `-i`. You may also try using [realtime and arealtime](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#realtime_002c-arealtime) filters. I suggest you to try streaming synthetic video first (`-f lavfi -i testsrc=...`) instead of canvas. Try smaller resolution (just in case CPU is loaded). Note that I don't know node.js, and I can't post an answer.

Comment: Quick tips: **(1)** You likely want to set size `-s ` before giving the input `-i ` (since it will be just RGBA with no header about dimensions). **(2)** When using `-i ` as input you don't have to worry about any "frame send intervals". It is not doing any live recording of the HTML5 Canvas object. FFmpeg will instead await and then package one second of video when it receives **enough frames** sent to it to that produce 1 second. **(3)** Isn't `-g:v` specific to hardware accelerated decoding like using NVidia/CUDA (_eg:_ not usable with libx264)? Never needed it so wondering if/how it helps.

Comment: @Rotem The NodeJS part is also reproducible with PHP (running FFmpeg) as a Process. For example on Windows someone can use Xampp server's PHP and the local FFmpeg.exe together. Other server-side options include Python, Rust, etc. Maybe that note helps any readers to test a possible solution...